# Windows 10, Docker and Mongo: Operation not permitted, terminating

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose

We are running Windows 10 with HyperV and Mongo.

There is a mounted volume to a local data directory. This works in Unix and Mac just fine. We read that this doesn't work in Windows 10 and it's simply not true.

The first time, it works. Then when we stop down mongo and recompose, we get the following error.

If we restart the Docker Service, then it works again until we stop and start Mongo.

```
mongo      | 2017-07-12T01:55:17.504+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 28595 1: Operation not permitted, terminating
```

Any thoughts or work arounds would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
Attaching to mongo
mongo      | 2017-07-12T01:55:17.485+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=1 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=0bb1e3123750
mongo      | 2017-07-12T01:55:17.485+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.5.9
mongo      | 2017-07-12T01:55:17.485+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: d5e9b4994557285017795d9ed9129341314da202
mongo      | 2017-07-12T01:55:17.485+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.1t  3 May 2016
mongo      | 2017-07-12T01:55:17.485+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
mongo      | 2017-07-12T01:55:17.485+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
mongo      | 2017-07-12T01:55:17.485+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
mongo      | 2017-07-12T01:55:17.485+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: debian81
mongo      | 2017-07-12T01:55:17.485+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
mongo      | 2017-07-12T01:55:17.485+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
mongo      | 2017-07-12T01:55:17.485+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { net: { bindIpAll: true } }
mongo      | 2017-07-12T01:55:17.489+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] wiredtiger_open config: create,cache_size=481M,session_max=20000,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000),statistics_log=(wait=0),verbose=(recovery_progress),
mongo      | 2017-07-12T01:55:17.502+0000 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (1) [1499824517:502361][1:0x7f24061bed40], connection: /data/db/WiredTiger.wt: handle-open: open: Operation not permitted
mongo      | 2017-07-12T01:55:17.504+0000 E -        [initandlisten] Assertion: 28595:1: Operation not permitted src/mongo/db/storage/wiredtiger/wiredtiger_kv_engine.cpp 325
mongo      | 2017-07-12T01:55:17.504+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 28595 1: Operation not permitted, terminating
mongo      | 2017-07-12T01:55:17.504+0000 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
mongo      | 2017-07-12T01:55:17.504+0000 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
mongo      | 2017-07-12T01:55:17.504+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] now exiting
mongo      | 2017-07-12T01:55:17.504+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] shutting down with code:100
mongo exited with code 100
```